# Most efficient way of ordering columns and creating rank variables

Tags: r

I have a data frame with several columns. I want create a function/loop or what might be more efficient to take the data frame, order a column, create a variable rank(with a name like rank_columnname) based on that order and add it to the data frame.

```
dat <- data.frame(indi1=rnorm(10),indi2=rnorm(10))

dat1 <- dat[order(dat$indi1), ]
dat1$rank_indi <- 1:nrow(dat)
dat2 <- dat1[order(dat1$indi2), ]
dat2$rank_indi2 <- 1:nrow(dat2)
```

This example does what I want, but in a cumbersome way. I've tried using lapply but I can't seem to update the data frame with a new column with a similar name.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can reduce your code to `sdat$rank_indi <- order(sdat$indi1)`. The `order` function returns already a "ranking" vector. For other solutions see the `data.table` package.

Comment: Also, something like `library(dplyr) ; dat %>% mutate_each(funs(dense_rank))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple loop to insert in "rank_indi" variables:

```
for(i in names(dat)){
  dat[order(dat[,i]),paste0("rank_", i)] <- 1:nrow(dat)
} 


dat
         indi1      indi2 rank_indi1 rank_indi2
1   1.45829065 -0.3322692         10          2
2   0.55972129  2.5031318          7         10
3   0.45870293 -0.6216859          6          1
4   1.03814922  1.4284271          9          8
5  -0.75211259  0.5600499          3          4
6  -1.89298552  0.8047825          2          6
7   0.03843679  0.6593377          5          5
8  -0.09808913  0.2513729          4          3
9   0.97862797  2.2650003          8          9
10 -2.07767889  1.0684134          1          7
```

*edit: made a mistake in the earlier code*